# How to calculate the average duration between two DateTimes and group the average by Date in separate list in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

So, I have the following `Model` structure:

```
public class MyAverageData
{
    public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? endDate { get; set; }
}
```

And I populate this data from another list like this:

```
var myAvgList = from x in myBiglist
                where x.filter == "Required"
                select new MyAverageData
                {
                   startDate = x.startDate,
                   endDate = x.endDate
                };

var noNulls = myAvgList.Where(x => x.endDate.HasValue);
```

The `noNulls` list looks like this:

```
[0]
endDate: {18/05/2021 5:32:12 PM}
startDate: {24/06/2020 9:34:16 PM}

[1]
endDate: {18/05/2021 5:32:12 PM}
startDate: {24/06/2020 9:28:57 PM}

[2]
endDate: {18/05/2021 5:32:12 PM}
startDate: {24/06/2020 9:22:35 PM}

[3]
endDate: {18/05/2021 5:32:12 PM}
startDate: {23/06/2020 5:44:01 PM}

[4]
endDate: {18/05/2021 5:32:12 PM}
startDate: {23/06/2020 5:36:44 PM}
```

I am attempting to find the average time between the `endDate` and `startDate` like this:

```
if(noNulls.IsAny())
{
    var avgTime = noNulls.Average(x => (x.endDate.Value - x.startDate).TotalMilliseconds);
}
```

This gives the average of the entire `noNulls` list. How can I find the average duration between two dates and then group them based on the date. Basically I want a list (based on the above data) that would like something like this:

```
[0]
Date: {23/06/2020}
AverageTime: {2500}

[1]
Date: {24/06/2020}
AverageTime: {5500}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: A point about naming. You are not finding the average between two dates. You are finding the time elapsed between two `DateTime` values (in milliseconds here), then averaging those durations over a specific time period (a day in this case). The phrase "calculating the average between two `DateTime` values" makes no sense.

Comment: `noNulls.GroupBy(x => x.startDate.Date, (k, g) => new { Date = k, AverageTime = g.Average(x => (x.endDate.Value - x.startDate).TotalMilliseconds) })`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I get your point sir. Could you make the update to the question so that it is not misleading to other readers also? Thanks

Comment: @GSerg Yes, that is exactly what I require. Much thanks sir.